# Steam In-Home Streaming with OpenVPN Server on ASUS RT-AC68U

Tags: router, openvpn, steam

So I've tested out in-home streaming with hamachi on mac osx. Worked flawlessly. Currently I want to host an OpenVPN server on my Asus RT-AC68U. I've got the server up and running and I'm able to connect to it with my laptop running fedora 22. However it is unable to be seen on the network and as a result, the computer that I'll be streaming from is unable to find the remote computer to stream the games to on steam.

What I was hoping for was some detailed instructions and a better understanding of what's going on so that I can configure it properly, so that the remote computer will be detected as part of the network. my setup is as follows:

Gaming PC (windows 7) <-> Router hosting OpenVPN (RT-AC68U) <-> wonderous internets <-> laptop running fedora 22.

To help this along here is my current configuration on the router - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ZEv.jpg

I then export the .ovpn file from the router and initiate it on my fedora computer by running this command in terminal - "sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn"

This is my first time really delving into openvpn and hosting a vpn in general so help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You must adverise your server side LAN to your client by using `push "route {Server subnet}"` in your server config [`{server subnet}` is equal to example: 192.168.x.x/24 ].  Also, your router must perform `NAT` using `iptables` on the client packets so they are seen as local traffic: Your router may be able to do this with a check box. More details can be found [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope])